# MVC4 add overload to a method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, extension-methods

As many of you know MVC4 has some great new features, I am struggling with the ContextDependentView trying to add an overload to it. I get an error saying no overload method for ContextDependentView takes 1 argument . My original code that was working was this

```
// This worked fine
return View(new ModelSample { getInfo= info, Retrieving= Retrieve })

// This is now what I have tried to do that doesn't work
return ContextDependentView(new ModelSample { getInfo= info, Retrieving= Retrieve })

//This is the method for ContextDependentView()


private ActionResult ContextDependentView()
    {
        string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        if (Request.QueryString["content"] != null)
        {

            ViewBag.FormAction = "Json" + actionName;
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.FormAction = actionName;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I obviously see that there are no overloads but how can I add an overload to the ContextDependentView method to accept my model like **return View()**..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this overload to your controller:

```
private ActionResult ContextDependentView(SampleModel model)
{
    string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    if (Request.QueryString["content"] != null)
    {

        ViewBag.FormAction = "Json" + actionName;
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.FormAction = actionName;
        return View();
    }
}
```

That should work...